# how to move jlabel every second?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel

i try to move it to the right(x++) every seconds

i try to  move it with thread..

1. how to do it? (and can see it move every second)
2. there are another way to do it without use thread?
3. what layout manager that i should use?

heres i try..

```
public class help {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("target");

    public help() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        frame.add(label);
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        label.setLocation(400, 300);

        frame.getContentPane().validate();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        mysterious();
    }

    void mysterious(){
     ////////////////////////////////
     // part of edit responding David kroukamp  
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         try{

            for (int z=0; z<10; z++){
            label.setLocation((label.getLocationOnScreen().x+10), label.getLocationOnScreen().y);
            Thread.sleep(1000);  
            } 
        }catch(Exception ae){

    }
    }
});
t.start();
    //////////////////////////////



    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        new help();  
        }
}
```

thanks a lot for any kind of help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Class names begin with capital letters i.e `Help`
- Swing components should be created and modified on [`Event Dispatch Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- A new `Thread` is created like this:

  ```
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          //work here
      }
  });
  t.start();//start thread
  ```

however I'd suggest a Swing `Timer` as it runs on `EDT`:

- [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

**EDIT:**

As per your questions I suggest using a `Timer` the creating thread point was for general knowledge.

The probelm is the Thread is not run on EDT Thread of your swing GUI where as a `Timer` does:

```
 int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      int count=0;
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           if(count==10) {//we did the task 10 times
                 ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
            }

            label.setLocation((label.getLocationOnScreen().x+10), label.getLocationOnScreen().y);
            System.out.println(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
           count++;
      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

**Reference:**

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Comment: ^^ thanks so much.. it work.. but there something, can you give me hint why location y of jlabel change? (i edit my code).. and maybe there advice for question no 3?

thanks for the timer

Comment: wew sorry.. its change because getLocationOnScreen() {that i dont know why} but if i change it with getLocation() its return normal

Comment: thankz.. i luv this part.. 
system.out.println(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()).. thankz

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `Swing` example of a simple puzzle game.

[Java Swing Shuffle Game](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-shuffle-game)

When you press `Pause` button the title will get animate until you release the pause. Similarly you can use it for `JLabel`. Source code is also attached.

Hope that can help you much.

Comment: @moprmopr: Don't neglect to up-vote answers you found helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you put that part of the constructor in a thread, then you can call `thread.sleep(1000);` (1000 milliseconds for a 1 second delay) and then refresh, which should move the target across the screen.

Comment: how? apologize because i can't get it..
can you show me the code?