# Java Game - Making the Enemy move on X,Y Point using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, multidimensional-array

Good Day all.

I have the following Declarations and assignments and would like to know how i make my Image (A JLabel which has an Icon - The Enemy Unit) Move. The Label is called Enemy. I have implemented The Runnable and my code below - the switch Cases are situated in the overriden Run() method. Please also indicate PRECISELY where you place/run each method/instance/Thread. I will later implement multiple separate threads to do simultaneous actions, but 1st I need this cleared out. This is developed on Windows - Net beans for a windows project - Not for a handheld device

```
static Point EnemyLocation;

// This throws an error - Might it be due to putting an implementable
// overridden method in a thread? 

Thread moveTheEnemy = new Thread(run());

public Window() 
{
    initComponents();
    EnemyLocation = new Point(
        (int)(Enemy.getLocation().getX() + Enemy.getWidth()/2 - 7),
        (int)(Enemy.getLocation().getY() - 3 + Enemy.getHeight()/2)
    );
}

// How do i go about running this run method in that thread?
// And Can i Run it on a button click? Simply indicating
// ThreadName.start in the Button wont start the actions.

@Override
public void run(){

    boolean stop = false;

    // A Method is to be added here to flag for when the stop
    // will change... Dont worry  about this part... I need
    // the Cases below to work.

    while (stop == false) 
    {            

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int a = rand.nextInt(4);

            switch (a) {
                case 0:
                    EnemyLocation.setLocation(
                        EnemyLocation.x + 4, EnemyLocation.y);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    EnemyLocation.setLocation(
                        EnemyLocation.x - 4, EnemyLocation.y);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    EnemyLocation.setLocation(
                        EnemyLocation.x, EnemyLocation.y + 4);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    EnemyLocation.setLocation(
                        EnemyLocation.x, EnemyLocation.y - 4);
                    break;
                default:
                    EnemyLocation.setLocation(
                        EnemyLocation.y + 4, EnemyLocation.y);

                    //It comes down to this Exception Each time...
                    throw new AssertionError("Failure to attempt Move");
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: If the code is as you've written it, than AssertionError will be thrown in 25% of cases regardless of everything else - rand.nextInt(4) returns 0,1,2 or 3.

Comment: Yea sorry im new to java but thanks for your input

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How do you make an enemy (A Label with a picture as an icon) move on a JFrame

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to move jlabel every second?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226164/how-to-move-jlabel-every-second)

Answer (score 0):

e.g. [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) tells you how to run a runnable in a thread (third example in doc). You just give the Runnable to the Thread constructor and start the Thread. However, i would suggest to work on your java rudiments and read some literatur on game programming before spending to much time on a non-sense project (excuse me).
edit: "non-sense project" seems to be, in fact, to be too offensive. What i meant, was, that you wont finish successfully if you dont understand the basics and your code/question tells me, you dont. I may be wrong however.

Comment: If this project was given to 30 People to complete Im not the one to Blame, blame the one giving it. I would love to work on Larger games... If you want to find it more interesting - This is a tiny bit to a larger Piece project where i have to solve the Circles of apollonius... Determine from where sound waves are coming from to detect enemy movement etc. Im new to Java too so thats why im asking here. Please refrain from giving unusable input on the matter... I could have given the entire project and just asked "Do it for me" indirectly

Comment: Your code contains so many basic errors and issues (variable scoping, coding conventions, erroneous static declarations), that the given recommendation to learn some **programming basics** first, is the only suitable. Else wise, allegedly solving one problem will get you straight to the next one. Good luck anyways.

Comment: As i mentioned im new to java... Basics come with time. Time i dont have right now. I have programming basics, java is another world to me. Once again - How do i make the label move>>>???

Comment: .setLocation(Point p) on the jlabel instance